# Ошибка. Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate

Maven+ Spring Security+ hibernate+postgresql.

Среда IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2

> WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - 
>   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt org.springframework.beans.factory.
>
> BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appconfig-data.xml]:
>
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   **Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory**

Comment: А в чем вопрос? И приведите часть кода, где возникает ошибка.

Comment: Ну если смотреть на этот кусок лога то можно сказать что у вас проблема в настройках инициализации бина с именем `entityManagerFactory`. Стоит заглянуть в XML-конфиг и найти этот бин, возможно не указаны необходимые данные или не удовлетворены все зависимости.